# Why comparing two identical byte array takes different amount of time to complete ?

Tags: c#, cryptography, md5

I am trying to compute hashes and then compare them to simulate timing attack in c#
This is the code i am using for this purpose:

```
private void btnHash_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    var firstHashByte = md5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txtBoxText.Text));
    txtBoxHash.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(firstHashByte);

    var secondHashByte = md5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txtBoxSecondText.Text));
    txtBoxHashtwo.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(secondHashByte);

    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();

    NormalEquality(firstHashByte, secondHashByte);
    //SlowEquals(firstHashByte, secondHashByte);

    stopwatch.Stop();
    lstBoxTimeSpan.Items.Add(stopwatch.ElapsedTicks.ToString());
}


private static void NormalEquality(byte[] hashByte, byte[] hashByte2)
{
    bool bEqual = false;
    if (hashByte.Length == hashByte2.Length)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while ((i < hashByte2.Length) && (hashByte2[i] == hashByte[i]))
        {
            i += 1;
        }
        if (i == hashByte2.Length)
        {
            bEqual = true;
        }
    }
}
```

each time i try to run this, i get different times for even identical hashes! 
Why is it happening?
I also noticed that using the following method that is said to generate a constant time for both identical and different hashes failes to do so, and it acts just like the previous method, generating different times for just anything! (identical hashesh or different hashes!)

```
    private static bool SlowEquals(byte[] a, byte[] b)
    {
        uint diff = (uint)a.Length ^ (uint)b.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length && i < b.Length; i++)
            diff |= (uint)(a[i] ^ b[i]);
        return diff == 0;
    }
```

Why is it like this ? Any idea?

( By the way as a side question:
Does C# string == comparison internally does this kind of array comparison or it is just another story?
Since whenever i tried to use == string on a Base64 version of hashes, i got 0 time, both for identical and different hashes 
I did :

```
stopwatch.Start();
if ( firstHashString == secondHashString);
stopwatch.Stop();
```

)

Comment: Because your benchmark is flawed, that is way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get different times because the stopwatch resolution is too low to measure so little code. Eventhough the resolution of the stopwatch is very high, the CPU still have time to run thousands of instructions between every tick of the stopwatch.

During the execution of the method the stopwatch will only go a few ticks, so the resulting times will vary very much.

If you run the method for example a thousand times or a million times, you get enough work to measure with small enough time variations.

Comment: Thanks, But that doesn't help either, still for the same identical hashesh different times are generated!

Comment: @Hossein: How much does the times differ? You will never get exactly the same execution time when you run the code. Many factors may affect the result, like other processes running on the computer, garbage collections, cache state, page faults, et.c.

Comment: Thanks Guffa, But i thought i should expect they are different to some extend, i can not comprehend how this timing atack is possible in internet! i couldnt get any meaningful difference in one system, How is it even possible to get the difference in internet!!

Comment: Well, that timing attack would be hard. But imagine that *on average* a comparison is 1 / million second slower or faster. Now do this comparison one billion times and add them all up. This can even work if the comparison is relatively slow, or if a random amount of time is added, as long as it averages out in the long run.

Comment: Thanks owlstead , i think that explains it to some extend:)

Answer (score 1):

There are any number of things that affect the timing of method calls, a computer is a vast system, and the tiniest change can become the proverbial butterfly. To be frank, tiny timing differences are nothing to worry about, what matters is whether it always produces the correct result.

One thing to try might be repeating the method call many times eg. a million or ten million times, and timing all of the calls eg.

```
stopwatch.Start();
for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
    // call test here
}
stopwatch.Stop();
```

If you repeat the above a few times, the timings should be pretty close together.

Comment: Thanks, But that doesn't help either, still for the same identical hashesh different times are generated!

Comment: Even if a program does exactly the same thing every single time and uses the exact same system setup, other things eg. other processes etc. will change how long it takes.
Do you require the method to run within a certain time? Why is it a concern that it's not taking the same amount of time?

Comment: Then how people in timing attacks can know the difference between the right and wrong password from remote places! i cant get a close result in a system , how is it even possible in Internet!
I was just playing with the idea, wanted to see it, if they really differ.

Comment: If you're trying to use timing to determine whether a password is correct, then this website may be of interest
http://www.findlaw.co.uk/law/criminal/crimes_a_z/500428.html
If you're not in the UK, there are probably similar laws elsewhere

Comment: If i were to hack into something, i wouldn't have bothered asking here:) I am trying to get the likelihood of achieving this on my application. as you saw i was testing both a secure and none secure version and was puzzled by the result of how the secure version is no different with the unsecured one in termes of result. 
Any way thanks